# What is the purpose of the assembler and symbol table? What is at a symbol's address?

Tags: assembly, mips

From my textbook:

> To produce the binary version of each instruction in the assembly language program, the assembler must determine the addresses corresponding to all labels. Assemblers keep track of labels used in branches and data transfer instructions in a symbol table. As you might expect, the table contains pairs of symbols and addresses.

Why does it need a symbol table? If we have a symbol table with a label name and an address, what is the use of the address? What is at the address... just the name of the label? Or is it the instructions of the label?

Say we have an instruction like this in assembly MIPS:

```
add_numbers:
   addi, $s0, $t0, 2
```

Why wouldn't the symbol table just store `add_numbers | <the_binary_representation_of_the_instruction>` instead of `add_numbers | <address_location_of_label>`?

Comment: because a branch to that label needs the address, not the encoding of the instruction stored there.

Comment: You're confusing assembly language and machine code.  The processor only knows machine code, which is basically groups of numbers.  It doesn't know names or labels.  Everything in machine code has to be done as numbers, aka bit strings.  Often, these numbers are distances, relative to something, like the current instruction, or a register.  Names & labels are assembly language, which has correspondence to machine code (they are used to compute distances/numbers that the processor will understand), but they are at different levels.

Comment: The result is machine code. That's series of byte values. That must reside somewhere in the computer, usually in memory. And memory is addressable by bytes, so you can have some byte at address 0, 1, 2, ... The result of your example is machine code for instruction `addi`. The "add_numbers:" label produces no machine code, it's just bookmark to the address where the first byte of `addi` instruction is stored in memory, available only to assembler at compile time. So it remembers that bookmark in symbol table and use it to calculate correct machine code for jump/branch instructions targeting it

Answer (score 3):

A label IS an address, it is a way for programmers to provide an address to the assembler but not have to know the physical address.  Let the toolchain do that work for you.

I don't remember my MIPS off hand so here is some pseudo code.

```
loop_top:
   nop
   nop
   sub r0,1
   cmp r0,0
   bne loop_top
```

Depending on the instruction set, but in general the conditional branch will be pc-relative.  Tables in general used during assembly with one or more passes on the table will resolve the distance between the branch and the destination so that the branch can be encoded completely.  Most instruction sets the above can be resolved in one pass. loop_top is a label that will have an address, but for the branch here it is pc-relative and you don't need to know the physical address.

But

```
   call my_fun
```

once making a pass on the code, the assembler finds that my_fun is not defined in this file and/or the assembly language has some syntax to mark it as external before used.  Either way it is external.  Cannot be resolved at the time this file is assembled.  So tables are required indicating the label name, and where in this object that instruction lives, depending on the assembler it may fill in the temporary offset or full address as zero for now or encode it as an infinite loop.

The linker later determines the actual address for things in the processors memory space, the linker will ultimately have a table of all (relevant labels at this phase of the toolchain) labels and their addresses while linking, then the linker will go back into the code and repair/create the machine code for this call instruction now that it knows what the actual address is for that label.

```
j hello
```

the object:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   08000000    j   0x0
   4:   00000000    nop
```

another object:

```
.globl hello
hello:
    j hello

.word hello
```

link them

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <_ftext>:
    1000:   08000402    j   1008 <hello>
    1004:   00000000    nop

00001008 <hello>:
    1008:   08000402    j   1008 <hello>
    100c:   00000000    nop
    1010:   00001008    0x1008
```

As objects all the toolchain has to go on is the label hello being used as an address to be resolved later.  In this case at link time, the linker works through the objects, counting bytes making a table of labels and their addresses.  During the first or some other pass it will change the instructions or data as needed to resolve these labels.

Now old school assemblers that did the job of assembling and linking from the same source file, the statement "assembler must determine the addresses corresponding to all labels".  It is not the assembler in general with commonly used toolchains that does the linker work.  So that quoted statement could use some improvement.  But hopefully this demonstrates that labels are addresses, they represent a yet to be determined address so the code is easier to write than something like this

```
  nop
  nop
  j pc-2
```

then if you add another instruction

```
  nop
  add r0,r1
  nop
  j pc-3
```

Or

```
   j 0x1008
```

then have to spend a significant amount of time re-writing the program to get each and every address hard-coded into the program.  Add/remove a single line and a lot of other code has to be changed.  Labels representing addresses make that all significantly easier and the toolchain determines addresses, then goes back and replaces the labels with addresses basically...

Added a nop:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <_ftext>:
    1000:   08000403    j   100c <hello>
    1004:   00000000    nop
    1008:   00000000    nop

0000100c <hello>:
    100c:   08000403    j   100c <hello>
    1010:   00000000    nop
    1014:   0000100c
```

If we didn't have labels and had to hard-code the address instead then you would have to change those three places as a result of the nop.  One line. If you added dozens of lines, hundreds.  How would you keep track of it all?  By putting labels in comments?  Assemble and disassemble and patch up the source over and over again until it looked somewhat right and hope for no bugs.

```
mips-elf-readelf -s so.elf

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 14 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 00001000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 00400000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 00400018     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     4: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     5: 0000a010     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 _gp
     6: 00002018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 _fdata
     7: 0000100c     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 hello
     8: 00001000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _ftext
     9: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _start
    10: 00002018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 __bss_start
    11: 00002018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 _edata
    12: 00002018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 _end
    13: 00002018     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 _fbss
```

and here is the one of interest:

```
     7: 0000100c     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 hello
```

the label hello once assembled and linked into a final binary is equal to address 0x100C.

Comment: Yes, MIPS has PC-relative conditional branches.  Its jump instructions are semi-absolute, replacing the low 28 bits of PC.  MIPS doesn't have a FLAGS register (instead using instructions like `bne r1, r2, target` or `bgez r1, target`) but fortunately that's not relevant for your example.

Comment: BTW, you might want to say "absolute address" or "final address" instead of "physical address".  Paging enabled or disabled isn't relevant to this, just convenience for branches withing a single asm source file, or how linkers work for branches between object files.

Comment: Yep, fair enough, was searching for the right word to use with address.